# How can I login on Stack Overflow with only e-mail?

Tags: support, login, google

Stack Exchange is becoming an increasingly more important part of my work. I recently realized that it is tied to my Google account. At present, I can only log in using Google:

[image: Google login]

I am not very comfortable with such dependency. What if I lose control of my Google account? After all, Gmail is a free service and they don't provide much of a customer service in case I lose my password/fail password recovery/get blocked out.

Recently, I switched to my corporate e-mail that I have a 100% control of. I was trying to add it as a login option to my Stack Overflow, but I can't find a way to do it. Below are the only options I see:

[image: Login options]

Is there a way?
If not, then why not?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704

Comment: Is this a Non issue? When you click logout there clearly are Signup options using just your email address.

Comment: @PeterB Adding a log-in to an already existing account is slightly more involved.